# Is isEmpty() method is applicable for $request?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to use `isEmpty()` method for validating a input a for empty field? I have a `validate($request)` where it has a multiple form to be filled up. I have additional form where it's not totally required.

Controller:

```
$this->validate($request,
[
    'title' => 'required|regex:/(^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$)+/|max:255',
    'content' => 'required',
    'category' => 'required',
    'approver' => 'required',
    'recipient' => 'required',
]);     


$document = new Document();
$user = Auth::user();
                                //Request in the form
$document->title = $request->title;
$document->content = $request->content;
$document->category_id = $request->category;
$document->save();

foreach($request->recipient as $recipientId)
{
    $document->sentToUsers()->sync([ $recipientId => ['sender_id' => $user->id]],false );
}
```

I have a form name `department` which is not required to be filled out. I'm trying to check if it's not empty it will insert this into database. If empty nothing will happen.

```
if(!$request->department->isEmpty())
{
    foreach($request->department as $departmentId)
    {
        foreach(Department::find($departmentId)->users()->get() as $user1) //find the users belonging to the current department
        {
            $document->sentToUsers()->sync([ $user1->id => ['sender_id' => $user->id]],false );
        }
    }
}
else
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use `empty()`:

```
if(!empty($request->department))
```

I guess `isEmpty()` is [for collection only](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-isempty) and you're checking property of `Request` object:

> The isEmpty method returns true if the collection is empty; otherwise,
>   false is returned

Answer (score 2):

Doing `$request->field` will give you the value of that field, be it a string, array, number or anything else. You can just use PHP's `empty` function to check if it's empty before doing something:

```
if (!empty($request->department)) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted by other answers the `isEmpty` method you're referring to is for collections whereas you're checking property values.

However, I wanted to add one very import note about the use of `empty` in that stead.

In PHP the `empty` construct is semantically identical to `!isset($thing) || !$thing` such that both `empty($thing)` and `!isset($thing) || !$thing` give identical results. The `isset` construct is simply used to determine if a variable is not `null` without triggering any use of undefined variable errors. Combine that with a boolean truth check, and we get `empty`.

This might not always be what you're after though. For example, in PHP an object is **always** *true* in the truth table. However, things like the integer `0`, and empty string `""`, or even an empty `Array` are considered *false* in the truth table.  Which is why it's always important to check the [truth table](http://php.net/types.comparisons) before you make your decision about which to use.

So for example, a zero-length string, may be empty to you, but it may not be empty to me if the expectation is that the user submitted the value `isset($_POST['thing']) === true`, but as an empty string.

You should also consider things like `<input type="checkbox">` where the expectation is that the browser will not send the value at all if it is unchecked. Or the fact that over HTTP, all values are initially strings. So you may want to use filters like `filter_var("false", FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)` which turns the string `"false"` (*that wouldn't evaluate to `empty`*) into the boolean value `false` (*that would*).

Comment: Thanks for this cheat sheet. It so easy to find a method you wanted to use.